# How do I convert 64-bit hexadecimal strings in R?

Tags: r, type-conversion, int64

How do I convert 64-bit hexadecimal strings in R?

```
> library(int64)
> as.int64("7f2d36a2a000")
[1] NA
Warning message:
In as.int64("7f2d36a2a000") : NAs introduced
> as.int64("0x7f2d36a2a000")
[1] NA
Warning message:
In as.int64("0x7f2d36a2a000") : NAs introduced
```

Comment: That's an orphaned package that has been removed from CRAN. Consider bit64: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bit64/index.html or Rmpfr: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rmpfr/index.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For a number that large, you'll need to load a package that supports representations of arbitrarily large numbers. **Rmpfr** is one example:

```
library(Rmpfr)

## Check that it works as expected on smaller numbers:
strtoi("ff", base=16)
# [1] 255
mpfr("ff", base=16)
# 1 'mpfr' number of precision  8   bits 
# [1] 255
as.integer(mpfr("ff", base=16)
# [1] 255

## Then apply it with (more) confidence to larger numbers: 
mpfr("7f2d36a2a000", base=16)
# 1 'mpfr' number of precision  48   bits 
# [1] 139832166883328
mpfr("7f2d36a2a0007f2d36a2a0007f2d36a2a0007f2d36a2a000", base=16)
# 1 'mpfr' number of precision  192   bits 
# [1] 3118361524223520784583964884878580812558070356334996529152
```

Answer (score 7):

Here's a way using `bit64`.

```
library(bit64)
str <- "7f2d36a2a000"
as.integer64(as.numeric(paste0("0x",str)))
# integer64
[1] 139832166883328
```

Comment: Careful with this. `as.numeric` is double precision and has only 53 precision bits. So it might introduce rounding errors in the last digits!