# Reasons for `'x' cannot be coerced to class "hexmode"`

Tags: r, hex

Trying to convert hexadecimal strings to numbers usable in R (64-bit), I tried (according to the manual page) `as.hexstring`. Unfortunately I get `'x' cannot be coerced to class "hexmode"` more often than I'd like.

In a quick test I found out that `as.hexmode("7fffffff")` works, but `as.hexmode("80000000")` does not. So obviously "cannot be coerced" actually means "*signed overflow*". I'm surprised that a system running on a 64-bit machine is limited to 31-bit numbers.

What I actually want to numerically deal with are strings like `0x12345678.12345678` (representing 64-bit numbers). Do I really have to digest these in four-digit-chunks and put them into a non-integer numeric variable?

Comment: There's a discussion of the limitation and some ways around it here: http://www.win-vector.com/blog/2015/06/r-in-a-64-bit-world/

Comment: And there are possible workarounds in this answer too.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26302706/how-do-i-convert-64-bit-hexadecimal-strings-in-r?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: I can vaguely remember dealing with long numbers on my 8-bit Z80 computer ;-)

Comment: Is there a specific reason why neither of `Rmpfr` and `bit64` are included in the standard installation? Also manual pages should more clearly point out what the domain of numeric-related functions (e.g. when converting a string to a number) is. Perl on 64-bit platforms can deal with 64-bit integers for many years already.

Comment: I guess because they are a workaround rather than a solution. Example pages in R are very variable in quality, relevance ... but then lots of languages have basically got nothing..