# How to get 64-bit integer value of xxhash64 in R

Tags: r, hex, bit64

Using the [bit64](https://cran.r-project.org/package=bit64) package, I am trying to create 64-bit integer hashes using xxhash64, similarly to pyspark's [pyspark.sql.functions.xxhash64](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.3/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.xxhash64.html).

With the digest package, I can create the xxhash64 in the form of a string representation of a hex, however I am not able to convert this to an integer64:

```r
str(digest::digest("foo", algo = "xxhash64"))
# chr "26af78b925a80acb"
```

For some strings, I can use `as.numeric`, but that has problems with precision and NAs produced by integer64 overflow:

```r
xxHash <- digest::digest("barfoo", algo = "xxhash64")
xxHash
# [1] "8107d13ec8130cad"
bit64::as.integer64(as.numeric(paste0("0x", xxHash)))
# integer64
# [1] <NA>
```

Is there a way to get xxhash64 values in the integer64 data type?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I convert 64-bit hexadecimal strings in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26302706/how-do-i-convert-64-bit-hexadecimal-strings-in-r)

Comment: No, as Davor pointed out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26302706/how-do-i-convert-64-bit-hexadecimal-strings-in-r#comment104789265_26304030

Comment: I would recommend using ‘Rmpfr’ instead of ‘bit64’: the latter does not allow natively converting from hexadecimal, it has no unsigned integer type, its implementation codebase is messy and, at a glance, does not appear to be very high quality, and I also just found an arithmetic bug in the library (`bit64::as.integer64(2L) ^ (63L - 4L) != bit64::as.integer64(2L) ^ 63 %/% 16L`).

Answer (score 3):

For hexadecimal values that fit into 63 bits (i.e. strictly positive signed values), you can use the following conversion function:

```
hex_to_int64 = function (x) {
  hex_digits = setNames(0 : 15, c(0 : 9, letters[1 : 6]))

  Reduce(
    \(value, digit) value * 16L + unname(hex_digits[digit]),
    strsplit(sub('^0x', '', x), '')[[1L]],
    bit64::integer64(1L)
  )
}
```

However, this won’t work for the value from your example (`0x8107d13ec8130cad`), since that exceeds 2<sup>63</sup> − 1 (`0x7fffffffffffffff`) and thus overflows the signed 64 bit integer range.

Unfortunately ‘bit64’ does not provide an unsigned integer type, nor does it provide a two’s complement function or bit shift, so manually implementing the above function for values ≥ 2<sup>63</sup> is rather onerous. I suggest using a different package.

The easiest solution I could find that supports values  ≥ 2<sup>63</sup> does a detour via binary representation and then tests whether the 64th digit is 1:

```
hex_to_int64_signed = function (x) {
  hex_digits = setNames(0 : 15, c(0 : 9, letters[1 : 6]))
  bin_digits = t(expand.grid(0 : 1, 0 : 1, 0 : 1, 0 : 1))

  from_hex = function (x) unname(hex_digits[x])
  to_bin = function (x) rev(bin_digits[, x + 1L])

  complement = function (x) {
    x = 1L - x

    carry = 1L
    for (i in rev(seq_along(x))) {
      res = x[i] + carry
      x[i] = res %% 2L
      carry = res %/% 2L
    }
    x
  }

  # Step 1: convert to binary representation
  binary = unlist(lapply(
    strsplit(sub('^0x', '', x), '')[[1L]],
    \(d) to_bin(from_hex(d))
  ))

  stopifnot(`result does not fit into 64 bits` = length(binary) <= 64L)

  # Step 2: from binary to integer64

  add = 0L
  sign = 1L
  if (length(binary) == 64L && binary[1L] == 1L) {
    sign = -1L
    binary = complement(binary)

    # FIXME: This does not work due to a bug in ‘bit64’
    if (binary[1L] == 1L) {
      add = -bit64::as.integer64(2L) ^ 63L
      sign = 0L
    }
  }

  add + sign * Reduce(\(x, d) x * 2L + d, utils::tail(binary, 63L), bit64::as.integer64(0L))
}
```

We can now calculate the `integer64` value of `0x8107d13ec8130cad`:

```
> hex_to_int64_signed('0x8107d13ec8130cad')
integer64
[1] -9149114050405004115
```

However, note the `FIXME:` comment! A bug in ‘bit64’ prevents it from being able to represent the smallest valid 64 bit signed integer, which has the value −2<sup>63</sup>:

```
> bit64::as.integer64('-9223372036854775807')
integer64
[1] -9223372036854775807

> bit64::as.integer64('-9223372036854775808')
integer64
[1] <NA>

> -bit64::as.integer64(2L) ^ 63L
integer64
[1] -9223372036854775807
#                      ^ THIS IS WRONG!
```

As a consequence, the `hex_to_int64_signed` function fails on the entirely valid input `0x8000000000000000`, but it works on both sides of it, i.e. `0x7fffffffffffffff` (= 9223372036854775807) and `0x8000000000000001` (= −9223372036854775807).

… as I keep saying: use a different package.

Answer (score 1):

The as.numeric is double precision and has only 53 bits, so that it will result in rounding errors in the last [0, 4] digits since 2^9 bits is missing where the possible values it can take is 0 to 512, for more details in base precision as.numeric see (https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/double.html)

Actually it happens also in your first example of "foo", lets use the as.numeric() and bit64::as.integer64 together;

```
bit64::as.integer64(as.numeric(paste0("0x", "26af78b925a80acb")))
# 2787579430961678848
```

Yet, it is not quite correct due to the 53 bit precision. The correct integer64 representation for that hexadecimal is 2787579430961679051. You can get this number using **Rmpfr** package as follows;

```
library(Rmpfr)
mpfr(paste0("0x", "26af78b925a80acb"), base=16)
# 2787579430961679051
```

Same for xxHash;

```
mpfr(paste0("0x", xxHash), base=16)
# 9297630023304547501
```

Comment: Thanks, this does work, however I asked specifically for a solution that results in the integer64 data type, because my use case requires that for inter-operability reasons.

Comment: @Jozef Unfortunately you really *can’t* do this meaningfully using ‘bit64’, since ‘bit64’ integers are signed, and the value in your example does not fit into a signed 64 bit integer without overflow (put differently, the result would be negative).